# VB.NET windows app chart x-axis shows "12/30 04:10" when LabelStyle Format is "MM/dd hh:mm"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, charts

VB.NET 2017 Pro windows app chart x-axis shows "12/30 04:10" when chart > props > char area > Axes collection > X axis member > LabelStyle > format = is "MM/dd hh:mm" and for today's date of 9/19/2017.

I also tried Format = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss" which as same problem and displays for example "12/30/99 04:24:00"

I'm trying to draw a line chart of sample values vs. x-axis time

Here's my code that executes for every new sample point to be added to line chart.

```
        dim plot_datetime as  DateTime = now

    ' Store latest sample's value and datetime:
        detector_datetime_buffer.add( plot_datetime )
        detector_value_buffer.add( plot_value )



    ' Copy specific range of input optical detector samples to chart's series:
    dim sample_index
    MAINFORM.Chart_optical_density.Series("Optical Density").Points.clear()   ' delete chart series points

    ' Add the present range of points to the chart series:
    for sample_index = 0 to  detector_datetime_buffer.Count - 1 step 1
        plot_datetime  = detector_datetime_buffer( sample_index )
        plot_value  = detector_value_buffer( sample_index )
        mainform.Chart_optical_density.Series("Optical Density").Points.AddXY( plot_datetime, plot_value)
        debug.print( plot_datetime & " " &  plot_value  )
    Next
```

Comment: Have you inadvertently set the series `XValueType` property to `ChartValueType.Time`?

Comment: YES!  Thanks, TTM

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it.

Here is the 'secret' map to the setting where I needed to change time to datetime:
chart  >  properties  > Series  >  XValueType  >  ChartValueType = datetime

Since the setting to configure the datetime format is 9 clicks deep within the chart properties labyrinth, here is the 'secret' map to get there too:

chart > properties  > char area > Axes collection > Members  > X axis >  Labels  >  LabelStyle > format = MM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss

Comment: you could also use:    .ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")